How to iterate over a range with a custom step?
How can I iterate over a range in Ada with a custom step ?
For I in Integer'Range
loop
    -- do something every 10 steps
end loop;

Can I define a subtype with specific step ?

Typically one does an explicit increment:
declare
   I : T := Start;
begin
   loop
      exit when I > Stop;

      -- do something every Step steps
      I := I + Step;
   end loop;
end;

Sometimes you need a slightly different test:
declare
   I : T := Start;
begin
   loop
      -- do something every Step steps

      exit when I > Stop - Step;

      I := I + Step;
   end loop;
end;

when that last increment will overflow. Or you can handle the exception.

Here is a way to run actions every 10th steps :
for I in Integer'Range loop
   -- do something every steps

   if (I mod 10 = 0) then
      -- do something every 10 steps
   end if;
end loop;

